# Application Settings "Profiles"?

Tags: c#, .net, settings.settings

I am using [this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869.aspx) to store settings for my program. I want the user to be able to choose and load different application settings at run time. (i.e. the user may want to load one group of settings for one scenario, and another group of settings for another). Can anyone recommend the best way to go about this? Do I need to use another method to read/write the profiles from disk to Settings.Default, or is it possible to use multiple instances of what I am using now without having to rename the files and re-launch the program (this is how I am achieving my goal now, but I'm sure there's a better/easier way).

Comment: One option might be to define a custom class with the settings properties that you want, store a List<> of these inside your Settings.settings and loads the appropriate one as the user requires it. Might need to invalidate your forms for the settings to take affect

Comment: So essentially this custom class would read/write the settings to/from the disk based on which profile was loaded? This is what I was thinking of doing but thought there might be an easier way to just have something like Settings.Default, Settings.Profile1, Settings.Profile2, etc but all of these would have different values for the same properties.

Comment: You can have Settings.Default, Settings.Profile1, etc if you maintain a fixed number of profiles and store each profile under a different name (and filename) and reload the application wide settings from the new settings file. This is however not a dynamic way.

Comment: Okay I see. I was hoping there WAS a dynamic way but it appears the way you mentioned (or a similar method) is the best way. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hey, your comment helped me out so I posted it as an answer.  I am new to posting on stack overflow so I hope this etiquette is okay. If you want, you can post your comment as an answer and I'll delete mine and accept yours. Either way, thanks for the help!

Comment: Posting a self-answer is good. You can expand it later with example code to show future readers how you did it, what issues you experienced and how the config files look like.

Answer (score 0):

It appears Bernd Linde's method of using a separate class to manage the profiles is most appropriate. It seems there is no efficient dynamic way to use Settings.settings to load data at run time so it must be handled separately.